# Matlab r2017a error with python "Undefined function or variable 'imfilter_mex'"

Tags: python-2.7, matlab

I got the following error on matlab r2017a runtime;

```
Undefined function or variable 'imfilter_mex'.
Error in imfilter>filterPartOrWhole (line 362)
Error in imfilter (line 178)
Error in imagePrepy (line 31)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v92/toolbox/compiler_sdk/pysdk_py/matlab_pysdk/runtime/deployablefunc.py", line 81, in __call__
    nlhsWasSpecified, stdoutObj, stderrObj).result()
  File "/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v92/toolbox/compiler_sdk/pysdk_py/matlab_pysdk/runtime/futureresult.py", line 135, in result
    raise e
matlab_pysdk.runtime.MatlabRuntimeError: An error occurred when evaluating the result from a function. Details: 
  File /home/ubuntu/.mcrCache9.2/imageP1/toolbox/images/images/imfilter.m, line 362, in filterPartOrWhole

  File /home/ubuntu/.mcrCache9.2/imageP1/toolbox/images/images/imfilter.m, line 178, in imfilter

  File /home/ubuntu/.mcrCache9.2/imageP1/imageP/imagePrepy.m, line 31, in imagePrepy
Undefined function 'imfilter_mex' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to run your compiled code on another system. For example, you compile your code with a Windows x64 system and you try run it on a Linux system - this won't work.

Your are using `imfilter` and this MATLAB internal function uses a MEX function, so it matters from which operating system you have compiled your code.

I had the some error and maybe it helps someone else!